# How install libgnutls.so.26 on Centos 7.1?

Tags: centos

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/ffmpeg-install.htm) to install ffmpeg on my server.  When I'm configuring the source I get the problem:

```
ffmpeg headers not found.
```

In that tutorial they say:

```
To Fix: Just install ffmpeg-devel using

yum install ffmpeg-devel
```

But if I try to enter that line, I get this error:

```
Error: Package: librtmp-2.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
            Require: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
            Require: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
```

But I don't know how install libgnutls.so.26. I can't find this package on my repo. 
What can I do?

Comment: Adding the EL6 version of rpmforge to a EL7 system is asking for a broken server.

Comment: Stop following that tutorial. It's ancient, out of date, and will not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case somebody else finds this post because they're figuring out how to install `ffmpeg` on their CentOS 7 system, this blog post has everything you need: http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-ffmpeg-centos-7/

Core commands, just in case the site goes down, are:

`yum -y install epel-release
rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
yum -y install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel`

Comment: still doesn't work for me. I keep getting error for libgnutls,ffmpeg-libs,facc

Comment: li.nux.ro doesn't look like a legit site to me.  Buyer beware?

Answer (score 1):

I had a issue where i could not run a program due to libgnutls.so.26 being missing. Simply installing gnu utils did the trick.

```
yum install gnutls
```

Comment: doesn't work - sorry

Comment: @Dani try `sudo yum install -y gnutls-devel`